# How to toggle between two components in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

i have two components Register.vue [[my_reg-page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OS4Z.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OS4Z.png)and Login.vue [[my-signin_page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9YHi.png) ][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9YHi.png), if the user opens register page in the browser (by using /register url), if the user clicks on the Login heading that user will be toggled into the login page(/login),similarly if the user opens login page over the chrome , if the user clicks on signup heading that user will be toggled into the registration-page, How to do toggling between two components,please help me to fix this issue.

`Register.vue`

```
<template>
<div class="main">
    <div class="container">
        <img id="side-img" src="../assets/sideImg.png" alt="notFound" />
        <p id="side-content">Online Book Shopping</p>
        <div class="box">
            <div class="headings">
                <h5 class="signin" id="login" :class="{ active: isLogin }" @click="isLogin = true">Login</h5>
                <h5 class="signup" id="signup" :class="{ active: !isLogin }" @click="isLogin = false">signup</h5>
            </div>
            <form ref="myForm" @submit.prevent="handlesubmit">
                <div class="fullname">
                    <p>FullName</p>
                    <input type="name" id="name-input" class="namebox"  required v-model="fullName" autocomplete="off" pattern="[A-Za-z]{3,12}">
                </div>
                <div class="username">
                    <p>EmailID</p>
                    <input type="email" id="Email-input" class="emailbox" required v-model="email" pattern="^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$">
                </div>
                <div class="password-section">
                    <p>Password</p>
                    <input :type="password_type" class="password" :class="{'password-visible': isPasswordVisible }" id="passField" v-model="password" pattern="^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{6,}$" required>
                    <i class="bi bi-eye-slash" id="togglePassword" @click="togglePassword();"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="mobile">
                    <p>MobileNumber</p>
                    <input type="tel" class="telephone" v-model="mobile" id="tel" pattern="^\d{10}$" required>
                </div>
                <button class="btn-section" id="btn" type="submit">Signup</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import service from '../service/User'
export default {
    name: 'Register',
    data() {
        return {
            fullName: '',
            email: '',
            password: '',
            mobile: '',
            password_type: "password",
            isLogin:false,
            isPasswordVisible: false,
            title:'Online Book Shopping'
        }
    },
    methods: {
        togglePassword() {
            this.password_type = this.password_type === 'password' ? 'text' : 'password'
            this.isPasswordVisible = !this.isPasswordVisible
        },
        handlesubmit() {
            let userData = {
                fullName: this.fullName,
                email: this.email,
                password: this.password,
                mobile: this.mobile
            }
            service.userRegister(userData).then(response => {
                if (response.status == 201) {
                    alert("user registered successfully");
                    this.$refs.myForm.reset();
                }
                return response;
            }).catch(error => {
                alert("invalid credentials");
                return error;
            })
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
    @import "@/styles/Register.scss";
</style>
```

`Login.vue`

```
<template>
<div class="main">
    <div class="container">
        <img id="side-img" src="../assets/sideImg.png" alt="notFound" />
        <p id="side-content">Online Book Shopping</p>
        <div class="box">
            <div class="headings">
                <h5 class="signin" id="login" @click="isLogin = true">Login</h5>
                <h5 class="signup" id="signup" @click="isLogin = false">signup</h5>
            </div>
            <form ref="myForm">
                <div class="username">
                    <p>EmailID</p>
                    <input type="email" id="Email-input" class="emailbox" autocomplete="off" required v-model="email" pattern="^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$">
                </div>
                <div class="password-section">
                    <p>Password</p>
                    <input :type="password_type" class="password" :class="{'password-visible': isPasswordVisible}" id="passField" v-model="password" pattern="^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{6,}$" required>
                    <i class="bi bi-eye-slash" id="togglePassword" @click="togglePassword();"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="forget-section">
                    <a href="">Forgot-password</a>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-section">
                    <button type="submit" class="login-btn">Login</button>
                </div>
                <div class="seperator">
                    <h5><span>OR</span></h5>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-groups">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Facebook</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light">Google</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'Register',
    data() {
        return {
            password_type: "password",
            isPasswordVisible: false,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        togglePassword() {
            this.password_type = this.password_type === 'password' ? 'text' : 'password'
            this.isPasswordVisible = !this.isPasswordVisible
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
    @import "@/styles/Login.scss";
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I understood the question wrong. But you just want the user to be able to go to the registration page when on `/login` and the other way around.

You could just add add link in case you are using regular router.

```html
<router-link to="/login">
  <h5 class="signin" id="login" @click="isLogin = true">Login</h5>
</router-link>

<router-link to="/register">
  <h5 class="signup" id="signup" :class="{ active: !isLogin }" @click="isLogin = false">signup</h5>
</router-link>
```

Comment: Thanks alot @Denny Mueller, it's working fine ,but when i hover on signup heading it displays blue line under the heading how to remove that one

Comment: I can recommend a read of https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-link
It adds an `active` class and you have to change the css around it to match your preference.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use vue router https://router.vuejs.org/
2. Create a parent component LoginRegister.vue and include both of them in it

```
<template>
    <div>
        <login-form v-if="tab === 'login'" />
        <register-form v-if="tab === 'register'" />
        <button @click="tab = tab === 'register' ? 'login' : 'register'">Login/Register</button?
    </div>
</template>

<script>

import LoginForm from "@/LoginForm";
import RegisterForm from "@/RegisterForm";

export default {
    components: {
        LoginForm,
        RegisterForm,
    },
    data() {
        return {
            tab: 'login',
        }
    }
```

You could also have the buttons in the child components and use $emit to change the tab

Comment: Hello @justrusty, is there any other way without creating another component means using directives

Comment: @Sravani instead of a parent component you could merge the 2 components in to one and have ```v-if``` on each ```<div class="container" v-if="tab === 'login'">...</div><div class="container" v-if="tab === 'register'">...</div>```